# Media Queries issue and Responsive View Tool in FF

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with media queries. I'm using the Responsive View Tool in Firefox to view my site at 480px. But it seems to be firing at 430px and not 480px. I've no idea why.

```
/*
 *  Gird layout for devices above 480px.
 */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
html {
    background: red;
}
}
```

I have no other code or media queries so I'm wondering if this is some type of bug.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you add the meta tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> ?

Comment: Mine seems to be ok. Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Updated question with screenshot @YaMo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the computed witdh of the `html` element after setting the responsive tool to 480 you will get a value of 465. set `overflow: hidden;` on the `html` element then check again and you get 480.

Firefox takes the width of the scrollbars into account when calculating viewport width, as opposed to Chrome which overlays the scrollbars.

Comment: Oh. Is there a responsive tool for Chrome? I wasn't aware there was hence why I've been using FireFox.

Comment: I've never used any responsive tool, I tend to just resize the browser window then add a breakpoint where the content needs fixing rather than adhere to preset dimensions. unless you are targeting a specific device width I would suggest following the 'ish' principle - http://bradfrostweb.com/demo/ish/

Answer (score 2):

You won't believe this, and I am posting this incase anyone happens to have the same problem.

At some point I had made my browser text smaller using (CMD and - on the Mac). It was breaking in the correct width but because my font size was smaller it was throwing me off. It was actually breaking in the correct place, but the Responsive Viewer wasn't displaying the width based on my font size.

Answer (score 1):

check your zoom, if you have zoomed in, width will be off. ctrl+0 to reset zoom to default 100%

Comment: yes it does. when zoomed - 480px could trigger at, lets say 460px, which would cause this type of misunderstanding. this exact issue happened to me.